# python class inheritance with separate script files

Tags: object, python-3.x, inheritance, python-import

I'm having an issue with my subclass not inheriting superclass attributes when the classes are in separate files.  When I run my main `bot.py` I get an error stating:

```
AttributeError: 'Serv' object has no attribute 'server'
```

Here is my example:

#### file 1 [bot.py]

```
import commands

class Bot(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.server  = "myserver.domain.com"

    def getserv(self):
        return self.server

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print( commands.Serv() )
```

#### file 2 [commands.py]

```
from bot import Bot

class Serv(Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        return self.getserv()
```

I'm somewhat new to object inheritance in python and am sure this is a simple issue that I'm overlooking.  Any help identifying my problem would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subclass's `__init__` makes no sense.

You should instead put:

```
from bot import Bot

class Serv(Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init()
        self.something_else = whatever
```

Then customize `__str__` or `__repr__` if you want to change how the subclass is displayed.